# Mysql2::Error: Column 'encrypted_password' cannot be null

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5, yaml, fixtures, ruby-2.4

Rails 5, ruby 2.4.0
Error: rails while running rails test

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'encrypted_password' cannot be null
```

My test: utilities_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "Has first name vidur" do
    get users_update_address_url
    assert_equal "vidur", users(:regular).first_name
  end

end
```

My Fixture: users.yml

```
admin:
 id: 1
 first_name: admin
 last_name: tukaweb
 email: 'admin@email.com'
 encrypted_password: <% Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password') %>

regular:
 id: 2
 first_name: vidur
 last_name: punj
 email: 'vidur.punj@hotmail.com'
 encrypted_password: <% Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to print the output of that Ruby code instead of just evaluating it, so you'll want to change your ERB delimiters from the evaluate-only to output.

In other words, change

`<% %>` to `<%= %>`

So in your case:

`encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password') %>`